# Is it possible to create sub-tasks automatically in Jira?

Tags: jira

My team is going to develop 3 jira stories `sign up`, `login` and `password recovery`. Each of them needs PO, UI, Front-End and Back-End do their work respectively.

To track their work, I need to create 3 similar groups of sub-tasks under corresponding story respectively.

For example, under jira story `sign up`, I have to create sub-task `sign up - product definition` for PO, `sign up - Front-End` for Front-End, and so on

under jira story `login`, I have to create sub-task `login - product definition` for PO, `login - Front-End` for Front-End, and so on

In case one might argue that the way above is not good, please discuss that on another thread [distinguish different jobs between occupations](https://pm.stackexchange.com/q/29705/40663).

Repeat similar work is boring, is it possible to perform the creation above automatically in Jira?

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do automated stuff in Jira through plugins that use their API. You could in theory have an external program do it, too. Last time I checked there is no batch or macro in the user interface, because if you need repetitive work like what you describe, you are most likely doing it wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I am indeed worrying about if I am doing it correctly. How do you distinguish/identify different jobs between occupations in jira? for example, how many tasks the PO has done, how many tasks the front-end engineer needs to deliver?